# How to bind "typing_extensions.Literal" into another module so that it can be imported from that module?

Tags: python, typing

To reduce my imports count, I'm trying to bind some typing aliases in a dedicated module, e.g. `colour.utilities.hints`.

In that module, for compatibility reasons and because I'm still running Python 3.7, I try to bind `typing_extensions.Literal` to a new `Literal` attribute:

**colour/utilities/hints.py**

```py
import typing_extensions

Literal = typing_extensions.Literal
```

Then I used the bound attribute as follows:

**colour/utilities/array.py**

```py
from typing import Optional, Union

from colour.utilities.hints import ArrayLike, NDArray, Literal

# ...

def orient(a: ArrayLike,
           orientation: Literal['Flip', 'Flop', '90 CW', '90 CCW', '180']
           ) -> Union[NDArray, None]:
    orientation = validate_method(orientation,
                                  ['Flip', 'Flop', '90 CW', '90 CCW', '180'])

    if orientation == 'flip':
        return np.fliplr(a)
    elif orientation == 'flop':
        return np.flipud(a)
    elif orientation == '90 cw':
        return np.rot90(a, 3)
    elif orientation == '90 ccw':
        return np.rot90(a)
    elif orientation == '180':
        return np.rot90(a, 2)
    else:
        return None
```

When I type check the module though:

```
colour/utilities/array.py:1077: error: Variable "colour.utilities.hints.Literal" is not valid as a type
colour/utilities/array.py:1077: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
colour/utilities/array.py:1077: error: Name "Flip" is not defined
colour/utilities/array.py:1077: error: Name "Flop" is not defined
colour/utilities/array.py:1077: error: Invalid type comment or annotation
```

Importing `typing_extensions.Literal` in `colour/utilities/array.py` and using it directly is fine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the binding from

```py
import typing_extensions

Literal = typing_extensions.Literal
```

to

```py
from typing_extensions import Literal

Literal = Literal
```

fixes the issue, I'm not entirely sure as to why though.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion for a slight improvement, but you don't need to explicitly define a new `Literal` variable. For example, you could also define your `hints.py` module as follows:

```py
__all__ = [
    'Literal',
    # ...
]

try:
    from typing_extensions import Literal
except ImportError:
    from typing import Literal
```

Then in another module:

```
from hints import Literal
```

Comment: Having it explicitly defined is helpful for Flake8 and shows the intent better. The Try/Except clause is a good idea, it should be reversed though, trying to import from `typing` and on exception falling back on `typing_extensions`.